# How do I get information within a multidimensional array without knowing in which section it's located?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a few hundred products in an array like this:

```
[195] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Product Title
                    [description] => Lovely product description
                    [price] => 5.50
                    [Images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => http://...
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [url] => http://...
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingInfo] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [cost] => 2.00
                                    [country_name] => United States
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [cost] => 5.00
                                    [country_name] => Canada
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [cost] => 10.00
                                    [origin_country_name] => United Kingdom
                                )

                        )
                )
```

So far, I got this:

```
// Loop through array
foreach ($decoded['results'] as $result) {

   // Print product title
   echo 'Title: '.$result['title'];

   // Print all image URLs
   foreach ($result['Images'] as $images) {
      echo 'Image URL: '.$images['url'];
      echo "\n";
   }

   // Print ShippingInfo cost for United States
   $me = $stuck_here;

}
```

As you can see, this is where I'm stuck. I need to print the `cost` where `country_name` matches `United States`. This can be in `[0]` of the array or in `[3]` of the array or in any other order. If it was in the same place always, I'd know how ...but how do I search within that array and then return the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the shipping info, and test whether the country matches the one you want.

```
foreach ($result['ShippingInfo'] as $ship) {
    if ($ship['country_name'] == 'United States') {
        echo "Shipping Cost: " . $ship['cost'] . "\n";
        break; // No need to keep searching
    }
}
```